# Error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid.
> Errors:
> Model1.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

I am trying to save my form data in SQL Server database and I am getting this message error on my page `.Add()` function.

I am using Entity Framework 6.

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow. can you explain and elaborate? what are you trying to do to get this error? also which entity framework version are you?

Comment: Entity Framework 6 of Entity Framework *core* 6?